# how to inject data into a form in symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, ckeditor

I have a call at my controller:

Controller:

```
    if($appointment->getAnamnese() == NULL){
        $entity = new Anamnese($appointment);
        $form = $this->createForm(new AnamneseType(),null,array('history' => 'Digite o Historico aqui'));
    }else{ 
        $entity = $appointment->getAnamnese();
        $form = $this->createForm(new AnamneseType(), null, array('history' => $entity->getHistory()));
    }
```

AnamneseType:

```
    $builder->add('history', 'ckeditor', array(
        'data' => $options['history'], 'toolbar' => $toolbar));
}


public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return array(
            'history' => "Digite o Historico aqui"
    );
}
```

and i want to inject that history information to my form but its not working as i thought it would be, just setting the 'data' option...

how can i do it?

the problem is that after inserting data, i cant put it back to the form..

Comment: I tried to change 'ckeditor' to textarea.. and still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [setData()](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.html#method_setData) function to set your data:

For example:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new AnamneseType())->setData($entity);
```

Or maybe even:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new AnamneseType(), $entity);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at it the wrong way.

You have to use options here.

to create the form:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new AnamneseType(), null, array('history' => $entity->getHistory()));
```

And your form should look like:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options){

    $toolbar = array(
        array(
            'name' => 'document',
            'items' => array('Source','-','DocProps','Preview','Print','-','Templates')
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'clipboard',
            'items' => array('Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo')
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'editing',
            'items' => array('Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','SpellChecker', 'Scayt')
        ),

        array(
            'name' => 'basicstyles',
            'items' => array('Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat')
        ),
        '/',                
        array(
            'name' => 'paragraph',
            'items' => array('NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote','CreateDiv','-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-','BidiLtr','BidiRtl')
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'links',
            'items' => array('Link','Unlink','Anchor')
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'insert',
            'items' => array('Image','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak')
        ),
        '/',
        array(
            'name' => 'styles',
            'items' => array('Styles','Format','Font','FontSize')
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'colors',
            'items' => array('TextColor','BGColor')
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'tools',
            'items' => array('Maximize', 'ShowBlocks','-','About')
        )
    );

    $builder->add('history', 'ckeditor', array( 'data' => $options['history'] , 'toolbar' => $toolbar));
}

...

public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return array(
        'history' => "Digite o Historico aqui"
    );
}
```

Comment: dont works.. i think the problem is not "where" the data come from.. because i think its never "going" anyway..

Answer (score 1):

Well, looks like the form is generated in the second condition and `$entity->getHistory()` returns null.

Edit your controller code as below

```
$historyValue = 'Digite o Historico aqui'; // Default history value
if($appointment->getAnamnese()){ 
    $entity = $appointment->getAnamnese();
    // Checks whether the history is not empty (null or equals '' in this case)
    if (!empty($entity->getHistory())) { 
        $historyValue = $entity->getHistory();
    }

}

$form = $this->createForm(new AnamneseType(),null,array('history' => $historyValue));
```

I'd highly recommend you to read the official documentation.

[Symfony Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html)

---

Form data is supposed to be passed from a controller.

Replace

```
$form = $this->createForm(new AnamneseType($entity->getHistory()));
```

With

```
$form = $this->createForm(new AnamneseType(), array(
    'history' => null === $entity->getHistory()
               ? 'Digite o Historico aqui'
               : $entity->getHistory,
));
```

Remove constructor from the form class and replace

```
if($this->history != NULL){
    $builder->add('history', 'ckeditor', array( 'data' => $this->history , 'toolbar' =>       $toolbar));
}else{
    $builder->add('history', 'ckeditor', array( 'data' => "Digite o Historico aqui" , 'toolbar' => $toolbar));
}
```

With

```
$builder->add('history', 'ckeditor', array('toolbar' => $toolbar));
```

If you are going to map the data back to the entity check [Forms official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html)

**UPD:**

To pass some value to a template from the history field edit its definition like:

```
$builder->add('history', 'ckeditor', array(
    'attr' => array(
        'toolbar' => $toolbar,
    ),
));
```

You can access the `toolbar` option by:

```
{{ form.history.get('attr').toolbar }}
```

There is better solution: [Create Custom Form Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html)

Comment: Well, i guess the script outputs 500 server error. You tried to pass extra option called "toolbar" to the history form field. I assume ckeditor field does not know about this field. The easest way to provide some value to a template is to pass the value to 'attr' field option.

Comment: no, thats not the problem..
the form is still rendering but without the data inside it...

Comment: in the template i can get the value i need, but how tu put it in the form?

  `{{ form_widget(form.history)}}</br>{{ form.history.get('attr').data}}</br>`

Comment: Provide us the entire code of the form and the controller classes with the new changes